# Why a closed interval is not necessarily finite?

Tags: calculus

In the book I am reading now, *Calculus, a Complete Course* b Adams and Essex, in the section on continuous functions there is the term "a closed, finite interval". The book defines "a closed interval" as to be consisting of all real numbers $x$ satisfying $a \leq x \leq b$. I cannot see how a closed interval might not be finite. I read some threads and it seems to me that the concept of "finite", when one discusses sets, is different and it means that when a set is said to be finite it means it has a finite number of elements. But here $a \leq x \leq b$  we have infinite number of elements. This confuses me.

Comment: I think finite means  bounded interval i.e end points are finite. For an example $[0, \infty) $ is a closed interval but not bounded.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Thank you for the comment. This is getting more complicated. I thought $[0, \infty)$ is half-open.

Comment: ... and $[0,\infty)$ is closed because (many equivalent reasons) a sequence inside $[0,\infty)$ must, if it converges at all, converge within $[0,\infty)$. So, it is “closed” because the sequence cannot “escape” :) whereas $(0,\infty)$ is not closed (e.g. the sequence $1/n$ “escapes”) and in fact this interval is “open”

Comment: Kaveh, indeed it *looks* half open. But it is actually “closed” at the $\infty$ end (this is very handwavy, really it’s better to define “closed” using topology!) because there’s nowhere left to go. $\infty)$ is the end of the line, so to speak

Comment: That book uses *finite* in *finite interval* in reference to its length, rather than its cardinality (number of elements). They wanted to avoid using words like *compact* or *bounded* thinking that this is better for the students to grasp, and create confusion like this.

Comment: @user85667 Thank you so much. Now, I get it and it makes perfect sense considering the text.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the interval (set) $[0,1] \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. This interval is closed and not finite because there are clearly infinitely many rationals and therefore infinitely many reals in this set.